# регулярка для дробного числа, НЕ начинающегося с 0 если есть другие цифры в целой части

Tags: регулярные-выражения, devexpress

Для WPF-контрола `TextEdit` из DevExpress15.2 мне нужна маска ввода для дробного числа (желательно заданной разрядности целой/дробной части), причём **никогда** не отображающая символ-разделитель дробной части, если пользователь сам её не пишет.
Стандартный вариант числовой `Numeric` маски наподобие `n` не устраивает тем, что даже если вводим целое число, всё равно отображается в конце символ разделитель дробной части.
Установка значений `MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="False"  MaskSaveLiteral="False"` такого результата не дала.

Решил реализовать это с помощью регулярных выражений как для дробного числа, таким образом:

```
[-+]?\d{1,32}[.,]?\d{0,6}
```

(спец.символы начала/конца строки не пишем, т.к. в DevExpress они уже подразумеваются; на случай ввода некорректного символа-разделителя дробной части у меня есть валидация значений)

Проблема в том, что она должна пропускать значения вроде (`120,345`, `102,345`, `0,123`) и при этом НЕ пропускать вроде `012,345` -- т.е. требуется маска для дробного числа, НЕ начинающегося с 0 если есть другие цифры в целой части.

Скажите как победить :) не обязательно регулярками.

Comment: Попробуйте `^[-+]?(?!0+[1-9])\d{1,32}[.,]?\d{0,6}$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew почему-то DX считает её синтаксически ошибочной :( и без символов начала/конца строки тоже

Comment: Тогда регулярки вам не помогут. Без блока предварительного просмотра вперёд или назад не получится одновренно применить условие и ограничить количество вводимых цифр.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew мне кажется вы не поняли мою ремарку про спец.символы `^`,`$` -- в маске ввода контрола они автоматически применяются, просто писать их в явном виде не нужно.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что `(?!0+[1-9])` не поддерживается.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да, проблема в нём; мне кажется просто указывать "не-ноль" если указали диапазон [1-9] явно не включающий ноль -- совершенно избыточно;

Comment: соответственно, рабочий бы вариант `^[-+]?[1-9]\d{1,32}[.,]?\d{0,6}$` перестанет пропускать например значение "0,123" -- и выглядит так, что это не решить регулярками, потому что надо как-то ограничить условием "не начинать с ноля" диапазон `\d{1,32}` **только** в случае его размера более 1 символа -- КМК, регулярки такое условие не потянут.

Comment: Всё упирается в конкретный движок и реализацию маскирования. [Регулярка моя работает](https://regex101.com/r/jgHKo8/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Вы правы. В DX15.2 эта регулярка вызывает синтаксическую ошибку в XAML, с которой приложение успешно компилируется, запускается... и падает при попытке её применить. Мне эту магию не победить  :) оформите как ответ, приму и плюсану обязательно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[-+]?(0|[1-9]\d{0,31})([.,]\d{1,6})?$
```

Проверка:

```css
input { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; outline: none; }
:valid { border-color: green; }
:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input pattern="^[-+]?(0|[1-9]\d{0,31})([.,]\d{1,6})?$" autofocus>
```